# Python UTF-8 Encoding Issue

Tags: python, xml, string, unicode, encoding

in the process of parsing xml from a website, I've managed to get lost in a bunch of utf-8 encoding issues.  Specifically, I have strings that look like:

```
u'PA_g\xc3\xa9p7'
```

When I print this I get:

```
>> PA_gÃ©p7
```

What I want instead comes from the following

```
print('PA_g\xc3\xa9p7')
>> PA_gép7
```

Here is my code:

```
def get_api_xml_response(base_url, query_str):
"""gets xml from api @ base_url using query_str"""
  res = requests.get(u'{}{}'.format(base_url, query_str))
  xmlstring = clean_up_xml(res.content).encode(u'utf-8')
  return ET.XML(xmlstring)
```

My function clean_up_xml exists to remove the namespace and other chars that were causing me problems.

```
def clean_up_xml(xml_string):
"""remove the namespace and invalid chars from an xml-string"""
   return re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', xml_string, count=1).replace('&', '&amp;')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take from `res.content` a binary string encoded in /most probably/ UTF-8 and encode it into UTF-8 once again. Binary strings should only be `decode()`'d, Unicode strings should only be `encode()`'d, except some  [special cases](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings).

Since `clean_up_xml()` works with binary strings, it would be better to just pass binary input into ElementTree, it will handle correctly:

```
xmlstring = clean_up_xml(res.content)
# let ElementTree decode content using information from the XML itself
# e.g. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
return ET.XML(xmlstring)
```

If you decide to refactor code to work with unicode then all binary inputs should be decoded as soon as possible:

```
# let requests decode response using information from HTTP header
# e.g. Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-16
xmlstring = clean_up_xml(res.text)
return ET.XML(xmlstring)
```

When asking question related to Unicode it is important to specify Python version, in this case Python 2 with `print_function` imported from the future. In Python 3 you would see the following:

```
>>> print('PA_g\xc3\xa9p7')
PA_gÃ©p7
>>> 'PA_g\xc3\xa9p7' == u'PA_g\xc3\xa9p7'
True
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! You were right, I was encoding where I shouldn't have been!